# Why would ASOS have a caution for Low Density Altitude?

Tags: weather, density-altitude, asos

I did my initial training in a high altitude area, where it got pretty hot in the summer,  so I'm not at all surprised when I hear an ASOS announce:

> Caution: Density Altitude (a few thousand above field elev.)

But recently, I was flying in SE. Kansas when it was extremely cold outside. The ASOS announced:

> Caution: Density Altitude minus 1800 ft

I understand that cold winter air can make the air extremely dense, leading to a negative density altitude. But I don't understand the **caution** part of it.

As far as I'm aware, low density altitudes mean your engine generates more power, and your wings generate more lift. Everything is better with low density altitudes, right?

What is the **caution** for?  What should I be looking out for?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

> Low density altitudes mean your engine generates more power, and your wings generate more lift. Everything is better with low density altitudes, right?

The potential danger in low density altitudes is that your engine generates more power than it can handle. Even without exceeding the maximum rated RPM and manifold pressure, you can exceed the rated power of an engine under low density altitude conditions.

At low temperatures the air becomes denser. At standard sea level conditions air has a temperature of 15 degrees Celcius and a density of 1.225 kg per cubic meter. 
When the temperature is -30 degrees Celcius, the density increases to 1.452 kg per cubic meter. The equivalent altitude where this density is found under standard atmosphere conditions would be about -5900 ft. This is called the density altitude.

When air with these properties enters the combustion chamber of your engine and is combusted to the normal exhaust temperature it expands (increases in pressure) far more that air normally would, resulting in excessive power.

This [FAA paper on Winter Flying Tips](http://www.faasafety.gov/gslac/alc/libview_normal.aspx?id=10520) says the following about the risks associated with low density altitudes:

> Do not overboost supercharged engines. This is easy to do because at very low density altitude, the engine "thinks" it is operating as much as 8,000 feet below sea level in certain situations. Care should be exercised in operating normally aspirated engines. Power output increases at about 1% for each ten degrees of temperature below that of standard air. At -40 degree F, an engine will develop 10 percent more than rated power even though RPM and MP limits are not exceeded.

Comment: Actually, manifold pressure probably would get exceeded, right? I mean, DA is essentially pressure, which means your engine would reach max MAP earlier than it normally would.

Comment: Since the temperature is very low, the density altitude is much lower than the pressure altitude. DA is not pressure under these circumstances. You can have sea level pressure with temperatures below 30 degrees Celcius, resulting in a density altitude of -6000 ft.

Comment: Right, brain fart. :)

Comment: Actually, I've been thinking more on this. I'm still not sure that's quite right; if the air is denser than standard, then your manifold pressure should rise accordingly. It's the exact opposite of why engines are robbed of power at high density altitudes - it's not that they are at the same MAP and somehow producing less power; they are actually never reaching the MAP they would if conditions were ISA... right? I feel like I'm missing or forgetting something, and googling like crazy, but not finding good resources.

Comment: Ok, I think I found a [Lycoming SB](http://www.lycoming.com/Portals/0/techpublications/servicebulletins/SB%20592%20(09-29-2010)/Engine%20Inspection%20after%20Overboost.pdf) that answers a couple of questions I had about overboost. Looks like 'full' power can be reached with non-redline-MAP power settings! Thanks for the response, led me to some interesting research.

Comment: @DeltaLima great answer, but it'd be even better if you included links to further reading (the Lycoming SB or anything else which helps explain your point) in the answer so that sort of thing doesn't get buried in the comments trail... simply a suggestion.

Comment: @BretCopeland. Thanks for the suggestion. It's way past midnight here so I will call it a day and expand on my answer tomorrow.

Comment: This is now a kick-ass answer (it was great before). Really nice work!

Answer (score 8):

The **caution** is probably the default prefix for a nonstandard DA notice, not anything particular to the fact that it's negative. You're correct that lower DA will improve performance, and an [FAAsafety.gov document on density altitude (PDF)](https://www.faasafety.gov/files/gslac/library/documents/2011/Aug/56396/FAA%20P-8740-02%20DensityAltitude%5Bhi-res%5D%20branded.pdf) doesn't discuss low DA at all.

Answer (score 5):

In addition to what DeltaLima answered, also remember that denser air means the isobars are closer together and that in turn means that if your altimeter reads correctly on the ground, the **same baro-altitude gives you less clearance from terrain.** Some instrument procedures have minimal temperature for this reason.